# Setting `orient` keyword argument for Tkinter Scale widget results in NameError: name 'HORIZONTAL' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry('600x600')

scale = Tkinter.Scale(top,from_=10,to=40, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scale.pack()
```

The following error appeared:

> `NameError: name 'HORIZONTAL' is not defined`

I want to set my scale to be horizontal, and my reference is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scale.htm) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mat and user2666750 : `import *` can be handy when you're experimenting, but it's a bad habit to get into. `Tkinter.HORIZONTAL` is _much_ better as it doesn't clutter your namespace with all the Tkinter stuff. If you do `import *` with multiple modules, things get _very_ messy if the same name is used in more than one module. :) As a compromise, you can give a module a shorter name using `import ... as ...` syntax.

Comment: @PM2Ring: suspected as much, that's why I didn't post an answer :-) (I don't actually know python.) Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Mat: No worries. I guess you're coming from Tcl/Tk, or some other version of Tk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HORIZONTAL` is `Tkinter`'s variable. If you want to use it you have to import it or have to use like `Tkinter.HORIZONTAL`

If you dont want to add `Tkinter` then you can do `from Tkinter import HORIZONTAL`